# Create Ruby on Rails project from an sql file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a previously separately managed sql file containing rather simple but large database. Would there be a way to import this sql file and generate ruby code as models using this data as a starting point for my future development?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

It will take some work!

And you'll need to post a WHOLE HELL OF A LOT more detail to get more than that.  ;-)

Taking a stab:

Rails can use legacy databases with a lot of effort manually specifying foreign key columns, table names, etc.  It can be done.  My suggestion, though, would be to convert the data in-place in whatever database you have by using a lot of `ALTER TABLE RENAME...` work and same for columns to make the old DB conform to Rails' convetions (primary key == 'id', table name is plural underscore'd version of model name, all that) before doing the import, and then you can just use plain vanilla ActiveRecord and all will be easy.